# How to give validation to each text box which should take only one character or digit using asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp .net mvc 4.

I am doing a validation for a pan card page.

I want to do ,only one character can able to insert for first 5 text box then only one number to next 4 text box and last text box should accept only one character.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <input type="text" pattern="[A-Z]{1}"  style="background-color:cyan; height:20px;width:20px;" name="txt1st" id="txt1st" required />
  <input type="text" pattern="[A-Z]{1}" style="background-color:cyan; height:20px;width:20px;" name="txt2nd" id="txt2nd" required />
  <input type="text" pattern="[A-Z]" style="background-color:cyan; height:20px;width:20px;" name="txt3rd" id="txt3rd" required />
  <input type="text" pattern="[A-Z]"   style="background-color:wheat; height:20px;width:20px;" readonly value="P" name="txt4th" id="txt4th" />
  <input type="text" pattern="[A-Z]"  style="background-color:cyan; height:20px;width:20px;" name="txt5th" id="txt5th" required />
  <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]"   style="background-color:blue; color:wheat;height:20px;width:20px;" name="int6th" id="int6th" required />
  <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]"  style="background-color: blue; color: wheat; height: 20px; width: 20px;" name="int7th" id="int7th" required />
  <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]"  style="background-color: blue; color: wheat; height: 20px; width: 20px;" name="int8th" id="int8th" required />
  <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]"   style="background-color: blue; color: wheat; height: 20px; width: 20px;" name="int9th" id="int9th" required />
  <input type="text" pattern="[A-Z]"   style="background-color:cyan; height:20px;width:20px;" name="txt10th" id="txt10th" required /><br />

  <input type="submit" class="btnPrimary" value="Update" />
}
```

I am not getting how to do this and how to give validation to each text box ,I shouldn't able to enter second value in the textbox.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this ?

Comment: Are you wanting both client side and server side validation? Are you using jquery.validation.unobtrusive?

Comment: only client side @StephenMuecke

Comment: no i am not using jquery.validation.unobtrusive.

Comment: Just copied the first input (`pattern="[A-Z]{1}"`) to my project at it works fine - I get error message and submit is cancelled. Note pattern is not supported in older browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not at all using what MVC provides.
1. Create a model according to your requirement like,

```
public class PANCardDetails
{
    [RegularExpression("Your regyular expr. to validate")]
    public string Number1 { get; set; }

    // Do define the other properties like the above
}
```

2. Modify your form in your view  with the model as,

   ```
   @model PANCardDetails
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
       Html.EnableClientValidation(true);
       Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(true);
       @Html.TextBoxFor(pancardDetails=>pancardDetails.Number1)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(pancardDetails=>pancardDetails.Number1)
       //Similarly create the controls for other properties too
   }
   ```
3. Include the jquery, jquery unobtrusive and jquery validate files to enable client side validation and the MVC will do the rest in validating.

Answer (score 1):

I have done like this...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
      {
       <input type="text"  class="letter" style="background-color:cyan; height:20px;width:20px;" name="txt1st" id="txt1st" required />
       <input type="text" class="letter" style="background-color:cyan; height:20px;width:20px;" name="txt2nd" id="txt2nd" required />
       <input type="text"  class="letter" style="background-color:cyan; height:20px;width:20px;" name="txt3rd" id="txt3rd" required />
       <input type="text"  class="letter" style="background-color:wheat; height:20px;width:20px;" readonly value="P" name="txt4th" id="txt4th" />
      <input type="text" class="letter" style="background-color:cyan; height:20px;width:20px;" name="txt5th" id="txt5th" required />
      <input type="text"  class="number" style="background-color:blue; color:wheat;height:20px;width:20px;" name="int6th" id="int6th" required />
      <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]" class="number" style="background-color: blue; color: wheat; height: 20px; width: 20px;" name="int7th" id="int7th" required />
      <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]" class="number" style="background-color: blue; color: wheat; height: 20px; width: 20px;" name="int8th" id="int8th" required />
      <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]"  class="number" style="background-color: blue; color: wheat; height: 20px; width: 20px;" name="int9th" id="int9th" required />
      <input type="text" pattern="[A-Z]"  class="letter" style="background-color:cyan; height:20px;width:20px;" name="txt10th" id="txt10th" required /><br />

      <input type="submit" class="btnPrimary" value="Update" />
```

}

```
  <script>

     $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.letter').keyup(function (e) {
        if (this.value != 'A' && this.value != 'B' && this.value != 'C' 
            && this.value != 'D' && this.value != 'E' && this.value != 'F' 
            && this.value != 'G'&& this.value != 'H'&& this.value != 'I'
                && this.value != 'J'&& this.value != 'K'&& this.value != 'L'
                && this.value != 'M'&& this.value != 'N'&& this.value != 'O'
                && this.value != 'P'&& this.value != 'Q'&& this.value != 'R'
                && this.value != 'S' && this.value != 'T' && this.value != 'U'
            && this.value != 'V' && this.value != 'W' && this.value != 'X'
            && this.value != 'Y'&& this.value != 'Z'){
            this.value = '';
        }
    });

    $('.number').keyup(function (e) {
        if (this.value != '1' && this.value != '2' && this.value != '3'
            && this.value != '4' && this.value != '5' && this.value != '6'
            && this.value != '7' && this.value != '8' && this.value != '9' && this.value != '0')
               {
            this.value = '';
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can Use this also
`<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"/>
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter Your Name" ControlToValidate="txtName" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]{1}" />`
For number input use
 `ValidationExpression="[0-9]{1}"`